# Any way to temporarily disable I18n fallbacks / Globalize3 translations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, globalize3

I'm trying to implement fallbacks for translated attributes using Globalize3 and I18n fallbacks. To get fallbacks up and running, I added to my environment.rb file:

```
 #support for locale fallbacks
 require "i18n/backend/fallbacks"
 I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Fallbacks)
```

And then in my config file:

```
   config.i18n.fallbacks = {'en-US' => 'zh-CN', 'zh-CN' => 'en-US'}
```

Now I have an app running where, if a field is not translated in the 'en-US' locale, it'll fall back on the 'zh-CN' locale, and vice versa.

However, this means that the fallback also occurs on forms on the site. This is undesired behaviour for two reasons:

1. Users might think that this means that this locale has this value for the input being seen (whereas it was inherited from the fallback locale).
2. Saving a form with these inherited values actually saves the translations as the current locale's values - so then all of a sudden you've got data on both locales, but the user may not know this (or know why).

I'd like to disable the fallbacks while on edit pages / in forms showing objects with translated attributes. Is there any way to do this?

I'm using versions of Globalize3 and I18n from svenfuchs https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3